# Compiling .scss file with Compass Compiler gets me a strange error

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am working on a .scss file and when I compile with Compass I get this error:

```
unrecognized file type: png
```

It claims that this is the line that is wrong:

```
    $factor : image-height(sprite-path($ico-retina-sprites)) / image-height(sprite-path($ico-sprites));
```

I am pretty sure that there is nothing wrong with the code because other people are able to compile their projects just fine, so I was wondering if you knew of another reason why this could happen (ie installation of Ruby version or something)?

Thanks!

Comment: what did you assigned value for $ico-retina-sprites and $ico-sprites?

Comment: Double check your images?  Some people have discovered that a corrupted image was preventing their sprite sheet from being generated properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. It don't entirely know why this solved it, but I just did a hard reset my local repository and cleared my compass cache and the error went away!